# emacs-lisp-mode overriding outline-level

Tags: outline-mode

I am changing the heading pattern for `outline-minor-mode` and have noticed that one needs to have the following

```
(setq-local outline-level 'outline-level)
```

because `emacs-lisp-mode` overrides the default value with own `lisp-outline-level`.

Can someone help me understand this?

For a custom heading one uses `outline-heading-alist` but for `emacs-lisp-mode` and others, it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand but want to understand. Please pose a **specific** question.